# Why multidimensional array only execute function on every cell?

Tags: javascript, variables, multidimensional-array, let

### Problem

I have a `Multidimensional Array` and a function called `conversion()`.

`let variables outside conversion()`
will only be executed on every other cell

`let variables inside conversion()`
works properly but you have to type the exact same variable in every new function

### What I'm looking for?

I would like to know why this is happening
If I knew why, then I can fix the problem
But at the moment I don't know why

### Works… Kinda

Only executes function on every other cell

```js
let MDA = [
  [ '','','UndefineD','nuLL','trUe','fAlsE','TruE','FalSe','NaN','NAN'],
  [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '8', '9', '10' ],
  [ 'a', 'TrUe', 'FaLsE', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ]
],
    regComma = /\b(,")(.*?(?:(?!\b,".*",).)*)(",)/g,
    regNumber = /^((\s+)?((-)|\.)?)?[\d\.]+(\s+)?$/g,
    regBoolean = /^(\s+)?(true|false)(\s+)?$/gi,
    regUndefined = /^(\s+)?(undefined|null)(\s+)?$/gi,
    regNaN = /^(\s)?nan(\s)?$/gi;

function conversion(str) {
  if (regNumber.test(str)) {return parseInt(str);}
  if (regBoolean.test(str)) {return /t/i.test(str)?true:false;}
  if (regUndefined.test(str)) {return /d/i.test(str)?undefined:null;}
  if (regNaN.test(str)) {return NaN;}
  return str;
}


for(var i = 0; i < MDA.length; i++) {
    let cube = MDA[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
    let cell = cube[j],
     convert = conversion(cell);
      MDA[i][j] = convert;
    }
}

console.log(MDA)
```

### Works Properly

Inefficient due to me having to write variables
into each function I want preformed on each cell.

```js
let MDA = [
  [ '','','UndefineD','nuLL','trUe','fAlsE','TruE','FalSe','NaN','NAN'],
  [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '8', '9', '10' ],
  [ 'a', 'TrUe', 'FaLsE', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ]
];

function conversion(str) {
  let regComma = /\b(,")(.*?(?:(?!\b,".*",).)*)(",)/g,
      regNumber = /^((\s+)?((-)|\.)?)?[\d\.]+(\s+)?$/g,
      regBoolean = /^(\s+)?(true|false)(\s+)?$/gi,
      regUndefined = /^(\s+)?(undefined|null)(\s+)?$/gi,
      regNaN = /^(\s)?nan(\s)?$/gi;
  if (regNumber.test(str)) {return parseInt(str);}
  if (regBoolean.test(str)) {return /t/i.test(str)?true:false;}
  if (regUndefined.test(str)) {return /d/i.test(str)?undefined:null;}
  if (regNaN.test(str)) {return NaN;}
  return str;
}


for(var i = 0; i < MDA.length; i++) {
    let cube = MDA[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
    let cell = cube[j],
     convert = conversion(cell);
      MDA[i][j] = convert;
    }
}

console.log(MDA)
```

### What I've Tried

Placed the `let` variables outside `conversion()`
Created new `let` variables referenced to outside variables
But it only works on every other cell

```js
let MDA = [
  [ '','','UndefineD','nuLL','trUe','fAlsE','TruE','FalSe','NaN','NAN'],
  [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '8', '9', '10' ],
  [ 'a', 'TrUe', 'FaLsE', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ]
],
  regComma = /\b(,")(.*?(?:(?!\b,".*",).)*)(",)/g,
  regNumber = /^((\s+)?((-)|\.)?)?[\d\.]+(\s+)?$/g,
  regBoolean = /^(\s+)?(true|false)(\s+)?$/gi,
  regUndefined = /^(\s+)?(undefined|null)(\s+)?$/gi,
  regNaN = /^(\s)?nan(\s)?$/gi;

function conversion(str) {
  let r1 = regComma,
      r2 = regNumber,
      r3 = regBoolean,
      r4 = regUndefined,
      r5 = regNaN;
  if (r2.test(str)) {return parseInt(str);}
  if (r3.test(str)) {return /t/i.test(str)?true:false;}
  if (r4.test(str)) {return /d/i.test(str)?undefined:null;}
  if (r5.test(str)) {return NaN;}
  return str;
}


for(var i = 0; i < MDA.length; i++) {
    let cube = MDA[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
    let cell = cube[j],
     convert = conversion(cell);
      MDA[i][j] = convert;
    }
}

console.log(MDA)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> `test()` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.
>
> If the regex has the global flag set, `test()` will advance the `lastIndex` of the regex. A subsequent use of `test()` will start the search at the `substring` of `str` specified by lastIndex (`exec()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property). It is worth noting that the `lastIndex` will not reset when testing a different string.

Hence was causing this behavior. Removing the `g` from the regex would give your expected behavior.

```js
const MDA = [
  [ '','','UndefineD','nuLL','trUe','fAlsE','TruE','FalSe','NaN','NAN'],
  [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '8', '9', '10' ],
  [ 'a', 'TrUe', 'FaLsE', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ]
];
  
const  regComma = /\b(,")(.*?(?:(?!\b,".*",).)*)(",)/,
    regNumber = /^((\s+)?((-)|\.)?)?[\d\.]+(\s+)?$/,
    regBoolean = /^(\s+)?(true|false)(\s+)?$/i,
    regUndefined = /^(\s+)?(undefined|null)(\s+)?$/i,
    regNaN = /^(\s)?nan(\s)?$/i;

function conversion(str) {
  if (regNumber.test(str)) {return parseInt(str);}
  if (regBoolean.test(str)) {return /t/i.test(str)?true:false;}
  if (regUndefined.test(str)) {return /d/i.test(str)?undefined:null;}
  if (regNaN.test(str)) {return NaN;}
  return str;
}


for(var i = 0; i < MDA.length; i++) {
    const cube = MDA[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
    const cell = cube[j],
     convert = conversion(cell);
      MDA[i][j] = convert;
    }
}

console.log(MDA);
```

Great Question. Thanks for it.